# matplotlib - loglog is giving me broken plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am embedding my plots into a GTK2 program. As you can see from my two pictures below, if I plot my data in a linear fashion the graph is fine, but using the `loglog` method gives me an unusable graph:

[image: Linear sample]
[image: Log-Log example]

The same data was used to generate both of these graphs. Below is the code:

```
win2 = gtk.Window()
win2.set_default_size(400,300)
win2.set_title("Embedding in GTK")
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(5, 8), dpi=100)
freqStart = float(txtFreqStart.get_text())
freqEnd = float(txtFreqEnd.get_text())

vbox2 = gtk.VBox()
win2.add(vbox2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(221)
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(222)
ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(223)
ax5 = fig2.add_subplot(224)

ya = list(subData[ls / 0.005:le / 0.005])

for i in xrange(0, len(ya)):
    if ya[i] < 0:
        ya[i] = 0

yb = list(subData[ls / 0.005:le / 0.005])

for i in xrange(0, len(yb)):
    if yb[i] > 0:
        yb[i] = 0

Ya = fft(ya)
Yb = fft(yb)

ax2.plot(list(frange(ls, le, 0.005)), ya)
ax3.plot(list(frange(ls, le, 0.005)), yb)

if radLoglog.get_active():
    print ax4.loglog(list(frange(freqStart, freqEnd, 1)), Ya[freqStart:freqEnd])[0].get_xdata()
    ax5.loglog(list(frange(freqStart, freqEnd, 1)), Yb[freqStart:freqEnd])
else:
    print ax4.plot(list(frange(freqStart, freqEnd, 1)), Ya[freqStart:freqEnd])[0].get_xdata()
    ax5.plot(list(frange(freqStart, freqEnd, 1)), Yb[freqStart:freqEnd])

canvas2 = FigureCanvas(fig2)
canvas2.draw()
vbox2.pack_end(canvas2)

toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar(canvas2, win2)
vbox2.pack_start(toolbar2, False, False)

win2.show_all()
```

Comment: you have negative and zero values. `log(x)` when `x <= 0` is undefined. plots look correct to me. try masking the zeros

Comment: just a tip: the GUI code is irrelevant. it would be more helpful to include code that generates (fake) data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I slipped up and forgot to take the absolute value of the FFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PaulH says in the comments this is the *correct* behavior.

`log` of a negative number is undefined, which `numpy` deals with by returning NaN (`np.isnan(np.log(-1))`).  `matplotlib` masks out NaNs when plotting.